# How to have python 2 and 3 in virtualenv

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv

I have a virtualenv (python2api) made in python2.7 on Ubuntu 16.04.  In the virtualenv I installed python3.5:

```
$ virtualenv -p python3.5 python2api
```

Then I installed pip3:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

But when I run 'which pip' it shows that pip3 installed outside of the virtualenv and any pip3 packages I install go to '/usr/lib/python2.7' instead of '/var/env/python2api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/'.

```
(python2api) user@comp:/var/env/python2api/lib$ which pip
/var/env/python2api/bin/pip
(python2api) user@comp:/var/env/python2api/lib$ which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
```

Is there a way to make pip3 install packages in the virtualenv?  It seems like only python2 or only python3 packages can exist in the virtualenv.

Comment: What version of virtualenv are you using? My Python 3 virtualenvs all have a `pip3` script (which is just a copy of the `pip` script).

Comment: virtualenv==15.0.1, virtualenv-clone==0.2.5, virtualenvwrapper==4.3.1.  If I make a python3 virtualenv then my python3 packages install in the virtualenv but my python2 packages install to /usr/lib/python2.7.

Comment: Yes, a virtualenv only covers *one version of Python*. You can't use them to manage both Python 2 and Python 3 versions in one environment.

Comment: Ok.  I understand.  Thank you!

Comment: ⁺1 for salad username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A virtualenv encapsulates **one version of Python**.

You can't use it to manage more than one version, and Python 2.x and Python 3.x are separate versions here.

Use two separate virtualenvs, one for each Python version.